# ruby regex allow A-Z, a-z, 0-9, periods, hyphens, and spaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, activerecord

I am trying to write a regex pattern with rubular to allow a person to add their company name like so:

```
  validates :name,
          presence: true,
          length: { minimum: 5 },
          format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z\d\s.-]*\z/, message: :bad_format }
```

However, this is not working.  I want to allow all A-Z, a-z, 0-9, spaces, periods, and hyphens.  I want to make sure to reject anything else including line breaks.

[image]

Comment: what is not working? please add examples

Comment: check http://rubular.com/r/E52CNHSDy4

Comment: @Artem I added examples on how the \n is getting through, thoughts?

Comment: @Artem I like where you went with that, thoughts on http://rubular.com/r/JNRUEfawSh

Comment: i suggest to use \A and \z to get string as a whole, and space instead \s, check the link above

Comment: note: \w includes underscore

Comment: @Artem if you want to add that as an answer I will make sure to toss you credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\A` ans `\z` as string borders instead `^` and `$` (line borders).

Use space instead `\s` (includes line break).

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/E52CNHSDy4)